# "01"-string representing bytes to unicode conversion in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

If I have byte - `11001010` or `01001010`, how can I convert it back to Unicode if it is a valid code point?

I can take inputs and do a regex check on the input, but that would be a crude way of doing it, and it will be only limited to UTF-8. If I want to extend in future, how can I optimise the solution?

The input is string with 0's and 1's - 
`11001010` This is invalid

or `01001010` This is valid

or `11010010 11001110` This is invalid

Comment: Do you have an actual byte or do you have a string with zeros and ones that can be decoded as a binary value? Or do you have an integer literal using the `0b..` notation?

Comment: Also, UTF-8 is a multi-byte codec, one single byte would either be an ASCII codepoint or an incomplete sequence. Do you have more bytes?

Comment: The input is a string with 0's and 1's.

Comment: And are they always 8 characters long? What if there are more than one, how are they separated? Is this extracted from a larger string of text?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: So whitespace separated, no other text?

Comment: Yes, whitespace separated.

Comment: Two of your sample binary values are invalid UTF-8 sequences, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no other text, split the strings on whitespace, convert each to an integer and feed the result to a [`bytearray()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) to decode:

```
as_binary = bytearray(int(b, 2) for b in inputtext.split())
as_unicode = as_binary.decode('utf8')
```

By putting the integer values into a `bytearray()` we avoid having to concatenate individual characters and get a convenient `.decode()` method as a bonus.

Note that this does expect the input to contain *valid UTF-8*. You could add an error handler to replace bad bytes rather than raise an exception, e.g. `as_binary.decode('utf8', 'replace')`.

Wrapped up as a function that takes a codec and error handler:

```
def to_text(inputtext, encoding='utf8', errors='strict'):
    as_binary = bytearray(int(b, 2) for b in inputtext.split())
    return as_binary.decode(encoding, errors)
```

Most of your samples are not actually valid UTF-8, so the demo sets `errors` to `'replace'`:

```
>>> to_text('11001010', errors='replace')
u'\ufffd'
>>> to_text('01001010', errors='replace')
u'J'
>>> to_text('11001010', errors='replace')
u'\ufffd'
>>> to_text('11010010 11001110', errors='replace')
u'\ufffd\ufffd'
```

Leave `errors` to the default if you want to detect invalid data; just catch the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception thrown:

```
>>> to_text('11010010 11001110')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in to_text
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```